# ¿Cómo subir una imagen de 1 o más MB a MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy tratando de subir imágenes a una base de datos MySQL con PHP.

El problema es que cuando subo una imagen de más de 1 MB me da error.

Les dejo cómo recupero la imagen y el campo en la BD:

HTML:

```
<form class="text-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">ARCHIVO:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success col-lg-6 mb-3 mt-3" 
     name="btnDisabilities"><i class="far fa-save mr-2"></i> Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Código PHP:

```
  $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $img_content = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
```

Campo en la BD:

```
image longblob not null;
```

Gracias de antemano amigos.

Comment: No es buena práctica almacenar imágenes en la BBDD. En su lugar te invito a que cambies el sistema y subas el archivo a una carpeta, y guardes en la BBDD la carpeta/archivo, para así buscarlo luego.

Comment: @Jakala y cada vez que quiera guardar un path en la BD, tengo que guardar la imagen en esa carpeta?

Comment: Siempre debes tener una carpeta uploads como base para los archivos que subas (imágenes, vídeo, documentos...). Luego ya será cuestión de añadir sub carpetas, o que se vayan creando a medida que subas archivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Puedes revisar el archivo php.ini? Tal vez los valores de 'post_max-size' o 'upload_max_filesize' son demasiado bajos

Comment: post_max_size=40M
upload_max_filesize=40M

Tienen esos valores Juan

Comment: ¿cuál es exactamente el error que te muestra?